# WooCommerce Variation fieldset add legend

Tags: php, woocommerce

is there a way to add a new html tag to a default WooCommerce variation structure? I would love not to adjsut the templates and do a magic trick with PHP to hook that new element in. So for the fieldset  tag we want to add a legend tag to display inputs for the selection

```html
<fieldset id="edition" class="kad_radio_variations" name="attribute_edition" data-attribute_name="attribute_edition"><input type="radio" value="Test-1" id="attribute_editionTest-1" name="attribute_edition"><label for="attribute_editionTest-1">Test-1</label><input type="radio" value="Test-2" id="attribute_editionTest-2" name="attribute_edition"><label for="attribute_editionTest-2">Test-2</label></fieldset>
```

```css
fieldset {
  border:1px solid gray;
}
legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
legend:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
legend:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  right: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="edition" class="kad_radio_variations" name="attribute_edition" data-attribute_name="attribute_edition">
<legend>Subscription info</legend>
<input type="radio" value="Test-1" id="attribute_editionTest-1" name="attribute_edition">
<label for="attribute_editionTest-1">Test-1</label>
<input type="radio" value="Test-2" id="attribute_editionTest-2" name="attribute_edition">
<label for="attribute_editionTest-2">Test-2</label>
</fieldset>
```